# MacBook Pro 2018 starts to run slow on a 4K external monitor setup in a hot climate

Tags: gpu, overheating, macbook-pro-retina

I live in a hot climate and every time I connect my MacBook Pro to an external monitor, after 30mins of using it starts to run very slowly.

It will only run normal if I will turn on my airconditioner and a fan that points directly to my MacBook Pro.

Is there any work around for this not to happen? Would an external GPU solve this issue?

Comment: Define 'hot climate'. Most computers hate running at ambient temperatures over 35°C & will start to throttle. The extra processing having to run a 4k screen will likely do that. eGPU might help - see https://support.apple.com/HT208544

Comment: Check your CPU/GPU thermals when using and not using an external monitor.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue unfortunately. The external monitor forces the MacBook pro to use the GPU for processes normally handled by the CPU.

Not sure if an external GPU would help for this. Sounds like it's worth trying.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).